# Display NSArray on window IB

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, parsing, window

I have an application that reads/parses data into a file and store it into a NSMutableArray.

I need to display the contents (data) of this array into a window (tableview or else don't care) the only problem is that the data is not static so i can't fix n labels if you understand me.

If someone can help me

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

This is for solve such problems that Apple design the [UITableViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
Follow the documentation and you should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not having an iPhone app but a cocoa app is this protocol will work as well ?

Comment: You can use the same for NSTableView: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html).